# Component rendered twice before useEffect as componentDidMount run

Tags: reactjs

I have an effort to reduce rendering component counts. But I don't know about rendering trigger in ReactJS exactly. I see 2 rendering trigger before useEffect as componentDidMount. And later, there is also 2 rendering triggers whenever state changing. I don't know why component does 2 render for just one state change.

My code in github: https://github.com/quangkhaidam93/1653033-covid19-map/blob/master/src/components/covid-map/CovidMap.js
Entire Project: https://github.com/quangkhaidam93/1653033-covid19-map

Image below shows console that have 2 rendering triggers:

[image]

Comment: The two console logs are intentional in development mode. Its not essentially two renders. Check https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects

Comment: Thank a lot. It is just one rendering trigger when I removed strict mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `<React.StrictMode>` Comp. It should fix the issue.

[This](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/1297) should give you more insight into the issue.

Comment: It works. Thank a lot. But I have one more question: Does it affect product version if I removed strict mode?