# Using then inside setTimeout callback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some legacy code that is using React class based component. Inside the componentDidMount it is calling a function lets call it `func1()` after 1 second.

It is supposed to call `func2()` only once `func1()` has finished execution. However, it is calling `func2()` meanwhile `func1()` has not finished execution.

I have put the `func1()` structure as well

```
componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.func1().then(() => { 
     this.func2();
    });
  }, 1000);
}

func1 = async () => {
 // do some long running operation
 await httpCall();
}

httpCall = async () => {
  await post();
}
```

Comment: Can you share `httpCall`? Does it return a Promise that only resolves once it's finished the HTTP call?

Comment: @NickParsons added httpCall

Comment: shouldn't do that ... unless `httpCall` doesn't return a Promise of course ... does `post()` return a promise (we're going to end up with dozens of function calls at this rate)

Comment: @JaromandaX post also returns a promise

Comment: [here's basically your code](https://jsfiddle.net/ha3zwo1d/) (post just resolves after 1 second) ... func2 definitely waits for func1

Comment: @JaromandaX I think it doesn’t work in this behaviour inside of componentDidMount()

Comment: why not? a Promise has no idea "where" it is. func2() will never be called until the promise returned by func1() resolves ... perhaps your actual code is doing something you don't expect or understand, and that is confusing you

Comment: Async functions always return a promise regardless of whatever is happening in the functions body and as @JaromandaX mentioned, func2 should definitely wait for func1 unless something else is happening that is not captured by the code snippet you provided

Comment: you're probably running react in dev mode with strict mode on

Comment: @SoZettaSho how would that change how promises work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Component rendered twice before useEffect as componentDidMount run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61547383/component-rendered-twice-before-useeffect-as-componentdidmount-run)

Comment: Just in case you are not aware, you don't need to switch to using `then` inside the setTimeout callback. You can write `setTimeout(async () => {await .......}, 1000)`

Answer (score 0):

*"By using async await inside componentDidMount, func2 is only called after func1 but be sure that both func1 and httpCall return Promises to enable the await keyword to work as expected"*

```
componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(async () => {
    await this.func1();
    this.func2();
  }, 1000);
}

func1 = async () => {
  // do some long running operation
  await this.httpCall();
}

httpCall = async () => {
  // Assuming post() returns a Promise
  await post();
}
```